# Failed to execute command on IP address return code 1

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping

When I am trying to bootstrap a node (Windows server 2012) using chef, I have encountered this error

Error : Failed to execute command on 192.168.10.22 return code 1

Error : Bootstrap command returned 1

[Screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPDL9.jpg)

Comment: This is not enough information to go on, please pastebin the full output rather than using a screenshot of just part of it.

Comment: show the command which you tried